# Hint Rewrite Cannot Infer Parameter

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I'm trying to create a Hint Rewrite database for a matrix library I've written. However when I write

`Hint Rewrite kron_1_r : M_db`

I get the following error:

`Cannot infer the implicit parameter m of kron_1_r whose type is "nat".`

`kron_1_r` has the type `forall {m n : nat} (A : Matrix m n), A ⊗ Id 1 = A`, so m and n should be inferred based on the context when autorewrite is called. I'm not sure why it wants a parameter here, or how to tell it to hold off.

Comment: Replacing `kron_1_r` with `@kron_1_r` seems to solve the problem, but the behavior still strikes me as pretty weird. (And in context, it means that I have to put `@` signs everywhere.

Comment: You are using maximally inserted implicit arguments. This means Coq is trying to insert them even if you haven't supplied any argument at all (right at the point you are trying to add hints to the database). Try making them non-maximally inserted.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do that? I've tried `Unset Maximal Implicit Insertion` without success. `Arguments kron_1_r : clear implicits` works, but I don't want to clear implicits altogether.

Comment: Try something like `Arguments kron_1_r [m n] _.` See the examples at the end of [sect. 2.7.4](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual004.html#sec112).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're running into the difference between *maximally inserted implicit arguments* and normal implicit arguments. The difference is exactly when you use a definition without giving any arguments, the way you are in `Hint Rewrite kron_1_r`. One solution is of course to use `@kron_1_r`, which gives the identifier without any implicit arguments.

Unfortunately there's no syntax when creating a definition to give it non-maximally inserted implicit arguments; you can only use `{m : nat}`. Instead, you'll need to use `Arguments kron_1_r [m n] _.` after creating `kron_1_r` to change the implicit behavior of the first two arguments (as suggested by Anton Trunov above).

It's often helpful to use `About`, which reports the status of implicit arguments (you get these with `Print` as well, but you usually get too much output when you print theorems since proof terms are large).